# Burn tags whose questions are all migrated

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed that there are many tags that **only** have questions that are migrated. Would it be feasible to have an automated process burn such tags?

Comment: Migration stubs are autodeleted after 30 days, and if a tag is only in use on deleted questions, it won't be available for use for other questions.

Comment: Interesting point.  I assume migrated questions arrive with tags from the originating site, which may not be relevant here.  What is the process for getting appropriate SU tags assigned?

Comment: which tags are those that you claim only have migrated questions?

Comment: @Sathya I don't remember, I'll go look later